# If I upgrade an image in docker-compose, will its volumes be lost?

Tags: docker-compose

Suppose I have a `docker-compose.yaml` file that has a postgres 9.1 service:

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.1
```

If it's upgraded to postgres 9.4, will the data in the database be lost? I.e., will the volumes be destroyed and recreated?

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

The data won't be destroyed. The `postgres` container will be destroyed and recreated, but links to dependant containers will be migrated. The hard part is actually migrating the data.

1. Revert to old postgres and take a snapshot. **Make sure** the resulting `migration.psql` contains sensible data, or your risk losing everything.

   ```
   sed -i -e 's/postgres:9.*$/postgres:9.1/g' docker-compose.yml
   sudo docker-compose up -d postgres
   sudo docker-compose run --rm dbadmin pg_dumpall > migration.psql
   ```
2. Remove old database files from the volume

   ```
   sudo docker-compose stop postgres
   sudo docker run --rm --volumes-from scratch_postgres_1 postgres:9.6 bash -c "rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/data/*"
   ```
3. Upgrade to new postgres and restore snapshot

   ```
   sed -i -e 's/postgres:9.*$/postgres:9.4/g' docker-compose.yml
   sudo docker-compose up -d postgres
   sudo docker-compose run --rm dbadmin psql < migration.psql
   ```

Details below.

### Test setup

We can test this by having a `dbadmin` service consume the `postgres` service.

```
postgres:
    image: postgres:9.1
dbadmin:
    image: postgres:9.4
    links:
        - postgres
    environment:
        PGHOST: postgres
        PGUSER: postgres
        PGDATABASE: postgres
        PGPASSWORD: postgres
    volumes:
        - ./backup:/backup
    command: bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"
```

Start both services and create a table.

```
docker-compose up -d
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql -tc "SHOW server_version"
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql -tc "CREATE TABLE foo (bar int);"
```

> ```
> fb905d183992    postgres:9.4    scratch_dbadmin_1
> 9316b431a369    postgres:9.1    scratch_postgres_1
>
> 9.1.24
>
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

### Without recreating the service

Upgrade the service:

```
 postgres:
-    image: postgres:9.1
+    image: postgres:9.4
```

Is the table still there?

```
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql -tc "\d"
```

> ```
> public | foo  | table | postgres
> ```

Yes, but the service still isn't using version 9.4:

```
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"
```

> ```
> fb905d183992    postgres:9.4    scratch_dbadmin_1
> 9316b431a369    postgres:9.1    scratch_postgres_1
> ```

### Recreate

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
docker-compose logs postgres
```

> ```
> Recreating scratch_postgres_1
> postgres_1  | LOG:  skipping missing configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.auto.conf"
> postgres_1  | FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
> postgres_1  | DETAIL:  The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.1, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.10.
> ```

That looks like good news: postgres has found a database but it has the wrong version. Since the migration isn't automatic, it's a bit painful.

### Migrate

**WARNING** This may well destroy your data. Only run these commands with this little test project.

First downgrade to 9.1 again. Then use the `dbadmin` service to take a backup.

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
docker-compose exec dbadmin pg_dumpall > migration.psql
```

Delete the contents of the volume:

```
docker-compose stop postgres
docker run --rm --volumes-from scratch_postgres_1 postgres:9.1 \
    bash -c "rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/data/*"
```

Upgrade to 9.4 again. Because we destroyed the database, this will create a new one. Then use the `dbadmin` service to import the backup.

```
docker-compose up -d postgres
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql < migration.psql
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql -tc "\d"
docker-compose exec dbadmin psql -tc "SHOW server_version"
docker ps --format "{{.ID}}\t{{.Image}}\t{{.Names}}"
```

> ```
> public | foo  | table | postgres
>
> 9.4.10
>
> 9bf94397f89c    postgres:9.4    scratch_postgres_1
> fb905d183992    postgres:9.4    scratch_dbadmin_1
> ```

Notice that the container ID of `dbadmin` is the same, therefore it is the same container - however, it is now linked to the upgraded `postgres` container (which was recreated).